# Ошибка: Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Я нашел статью в которой обьясняется как сделать паралакс для изображения в `lazyColumn` так вот есть там вот такой метод

```
@Composable
    fun ImageParallaxScroll() {
        val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()
        val list = (0..1_000).map{ "Item $it" }.toList()

        val firstItemTranslationY: LazyListState by remember {
            derivedStateOf {
                when {
                    lazyListState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.isNotEmpty() && lazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex == 0 -> lazyListState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset * .6f
                    else -> 0f
                }
            }
        }

            ...
    }
```

Проблема в том, что весь блок `remember` подчеркивается красным и пишется вот такая ошибка

```
Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate
```

Че не так? Не могу понять как исправить

Comment: У `firstItemTranslationY` тип должен быть `Float`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте импорт функции [`getValue`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#(androidx.compose.runtime.State).getValue(kotlin.Any,kotlin.reflect.KProperty)):

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
```

В случае `var` переменной, добавьте два импорта:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
```

И измените тип `firstItemTranslationY` на `Float`

Comment: Работает! Но от куда это можно знать? Я пробовал добавлять импорты это не работало, нужно было еще типо изменить

Comment: Тип у `firstItemTranslationY` можно вообще не писать, компилятор Котлин может вывести тип этой переменной самостоятельно.

Comment: @Sirop4ik Ну раньше приходилось гуглить и помнить. Потом  студия таки научилась предлагать в импорт этот `getValue` (правда я на бетах и канари сижу). Просто у вас наложились 2 ошибки